# Animate opacity change on hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div when a user hovers the element. I want that when you hover over div named distinguished the div class prod-desc changes it's opacity to 1.

Here's the HTML:

```
<section id="distinguished" class="four columns"> <a class="dist-img" href="#"  alt="" border="0" > <img src="images/e1.png" onClick="window.location='@Url.Action("Details", "Item", new { id = section["Id"], storeid = section["PortalId"], name = section["ProductTitle"] })'"/> </a>
  <div class="descContent">
    <div class="distinguished-bar"> <a class="categoryMain" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Item", new { id = section["Id"], storeid = section["PortalId"], name = section["ProductTitle"] })'"></a> <a class="btAdd" href="#" title="ADD"><span class="iconAdd"></span>
      <p>ADD</p>
      </a> </div>
    <div class="infoContent">
      <div class="prod-desc ">
        <p>Category</p>
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="prod-price">
        <div>
          <p class="priceTitle">Precio</p>
          <span class="priceRegular">$300</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonsBox"> <a class="btAddLarge hom2" id="addToCart" href="/Cart/AddToCart">
        <p>@this.Message("Add")</p>
        </a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('.prod-desc').hover(function () {
    $('.prod-desc', this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 1
    });
}, function () {
    $('.prod-desc', this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, just use in your code:

```
 $('#distinguished').hover(function() { 
    $('.prod-desc').animate({"opacity": 1}); 
 });
```

Here is the example: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqfrS/)

In your case you must refer to the element by id, which is *'distinguished'*. Then you define the action which is hover and inside of the function you specify which element and what to do, in your case *'.prod-desc'* animate (change css property) to *1*.

Remember to set initial css opacity property of *.prod-desc* to something lower than *1* to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead:

```
$('.prod_desc').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().clearQueue().animate({
        "opacity": 1
});
$('.prod_desc').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().clearQueue().animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
    });
});​
```

You can see it in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svNpQ/3/

Answer (score 0):

Target the element you wish to attach the event handler to, not the element that will have the fading effect :

```
$('#distinguished').hover(function() { 
    $('.prod-desc', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
    $('.prod-desc', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/acHGq/)